# Deselect any trackball/trackpad selection

Tags: android, selection, trackball, trackpad

Is there a way to programmatically deselect/wipe whatever the user has selected with the trackball/trackpad?

When I hit the back button on an Activity, the Activity it falls back to has a button that is selected as if the user had used the trackball/pad.  I'm not sure what is selected on the previous Activity, but obviously something is.  I'd like to programmatically wipe any selection just before the Activity finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the [JavaDoc for View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) I see a number of focus-related functions.

```
void clearFocus(); // drop focus from this view.
View findFocus(); // finds a view that is a child of this view that has focus, if any
View focusSearch(int dir); // finds the next view that can take focus in the given direction
void requestFocus
```

Sounds like `findFocus().clearFocus()` should do the trick (unless findFocus happens to return null)... you just need a handle to the other activity's View... which shouldn't be too hard if it's your code, or Non Trivial if it isn't.

If it IS your code, it seems like you could just add a clearFocus() to the button's onClickHandler.

Comment: This seems perfectly logical to me, but for some reason it is not working.  I've tried overriding the onBackPressed handler and clearing focus just before calling finish();.  I've also tried clearing focus inside the onActivityResult handler of the back Activity.  In both cases, I still end up with a button on the back Activity in focus :(  This ONLY happens when I type in an EditText on the top Activity.

Comment: I believe there's a change focus event you can Listen for... ah.  You override `View.onFocusChanged` and/or `View.onWindowFocusChanged`.  The info's on that same page I linked to earlier.